# T-SQL help needed regarding CASE statement in SELECT clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What is best approach

**Approach-I**

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'A' THEN ISNULL(UNIT,0.00)+ISNULL(UNIT_1,0.00) END) AS UNIT_SUM
FROM tblA
```

**Approach-II**

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'A' THEN UNIT+UNIT_1 END),0.00) AS UNIT_SUM
FROM tblA
```

1) my concern is Do i have to place ISNULL inside CASE statement OR outsite CASE statement.
Does it affect summation of units OR both query give same result.
And what happen if any UNIT column have NULL value.Does it result NULL of total.

2) do i must use ELSE in CASE statement as given below:

THEN ... **ELSE 0.00** END

Comment: Placing `isnull` outside would only affect the total outcome of `sum()`.

Comment: when happens when you try the possibilities?

Comment: with some of result set i tried and both gives same result.because in future record will get increased that's i'm looking best approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer to the original question:**

> *Do I have to place ISNULL inside CASE statement...?*

No you don't. [`SUM()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) ignores `NULL`s. Therefore the presence of NULL values won't affect the result of summation. The exception is when all values are NULL, or you don't have any values at all. In that case you'll get `NULL` as a result.

> *Do I must use ELSE in CASE statement..?*

No you don't for the same reasons.

> *...Do I need to use `ISNULL()` outside `CASE`..?*

It depends on what you expect in the resultset in case when all values are `NULL`s or you don't have any values. If you want to have `0` or any other value then use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()`. Otherwise don't.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5432/3)** demo

**UPDATE**

Given the expression like one in your changed question

```
SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'A' THEN UNIT + UNIT_1 END)
```

you most likely want to use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` around both `UNIT` and `UNIT_1` if you want to treat an absent value of one of these columns as zero values. 
In that case if you want to get a zero in a resultset even if there are no values that match your `CASE` condition  you **still need** to use `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` around `SUM()`.

```sql
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'A' 
                       THEN ISNULL(UNIT, 0) + ISNULL(UNIT_1, 0) 
                  END), 0) AS UNIT_SUM
```

or

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'A' 
                         THEN COALESCE(UNIT, 0) + COALESCE(UNIT_1, 0) 
                    END), 0) AS UNIT_SUM
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c5432/6)** demo

Comment: This is the most close answer to the question solution.

Comment: I have done little bit changes in CASE satement in question.Plz check.

Comment: @Sukhi That is very drastic change in your question. See updated answer. In short in such case you most likely want to use `ISNULL()` both inside and outside `SUM()` aggregate.

Answer (score 2):

You have other answers pointing out that you better put your filter `= 'A'` into where clause to speed up the query, and that's right thing to do.
I also want to note that your queries produce different results in case there's no rows to sum:

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'A' THEN UNIT END),0.00) AS UNIT_SUM
FROM tblA;
-- output: 0

SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'A' THEN ISNULL(UNIT,0.00) END) AS UNIT_SUM
FROM tblA;
-- output: null
```

If you want to get sum of all your rows and and put this data into columns, you can use this query:

```
select
    isnull(sum(case when code = 'A' then unit end), 0) as [A],
    isnull(sum(case when code = 'B' then unit end), 0) as [B]
from tblA
-- filter out rows if there's more codes in your table
where code in ('A', 'B')
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/95c51/7)</kbd>**

Comment: It would be more elegant to calculate totals one by one and finally join them. Your query it is not, at all, generalizable. It is not elegant the trip to include filter in where clause just to improve performance. A kind of redundancy code that don't match a easy maintenance code. Easy to fall into contradiction when statement grow up.

Comment: I don't think it would be more elegant to calculate totals one by one, try to do it with 10 elements and you see why. As about my query - it's much more generalizable, but I think there's a way to improve it, will try it when sqlfiddle will work (some problems with it now)

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the sum for cases where `CODE='A'` , then I would would write it like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(UNIT),0.00) AS UNIT_SUM
FROM tblA
WHERE CODE = 'A'
```

If you are selecting other columns too, then I'd do it like this:

```
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'A' THEN UNIT ELSE 0.00 END)) AS UNIT_SUM
FROM tblA
```

Answer (score 1):

Either, the right approach is:

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(SUM(UNIT),0.00) AS UNIT_SUM
FROM tblA
WHERE CODE = 'A'    --<------------ Index friendly
```

**Your approach is bad because it is not index friendly**. Also, with case statement, you should evaluate each row.

If you have more columns to aggregate you can perform a CTE query then join results:

```
;with cte_a as (
    SELECT 
    coalesce(SUM(UNIT),0.00) AS UNIT_SUM_A
    FROM tblA
    WHERE CODE = 'A'
),
cte_b as (
    SELECT 
    coalesce(SUM(UNIT),0.00) AS UNIT_SUM_B
    FROM tblA
    WHERE CODE = 'B'
)
SELECT UNIT_SUM_A, UNIT_SUM_B
FROM cte_a cross join cte_b b
```

**Edited** second query by @RomanPekar comment.

Comment: second query is really ugly, not generalizable at all, and even can be improved (`cross join` instead of `full outer join`, move 'total' into final select). I'd be shocked to see such a query in production code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use approach-II you dont need ELSE, so I guess in terms of having less code its better.

Answer (score 0):

Both variations return the same result:

The 1st replaces NULLs with zeroes **before** the SUM and the 2nd replaces a NULL **after** the SUM, i.e. there's no row with 'A'.

Btw, i would replace proprietary ISNULL with a Standard SQL COALESCE(UNIT,0.00).

And of course you could simply replace it with:

```
CASE WHEN CODE = 'A' THEN UNIT ELSE 0.00 END
```

Comment: it could produce different results if there're no rows to sum

Comment: You're correct. I assumed this is not the full query, there will be some other columns or a GROUP BY other_column.